# I have a column which has comma separated value how to search these value with an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

here is table

```
+----+----------------------+
| id |        title         |
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | math,science,english |
|  2 | social,hindi         |
+----+----------------------+
```

how to search column if one of the value match in the given array in my sql active record

```
$array=array('math','computer','english');
```

the result should be

```
+----+----------------------+
| id |        title         |
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | math,science,english |
+----+----------------------+
```

Comment: I understand this right in your table you have a column that contains comma separated value. i.e "math,science,english" and you wish to search for "math"?

Comment: simple don't have a column which has a comma separated value

Comment: why have a table with comma seperated values?

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql `find_in_set` method, [click](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) here to see the documentation.

Comment: but find in set use for one value i.e

Comment: $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('math,computer,english',title)");

Answer (score 0):

You can use   [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to solve this.

```
if($array)
{
    $this->db->group_start();
       $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('$array[0]', title) != ",0);
       for($x=1; $x < count($array); $x++)
       {
         $this->db->or_where("FIND_IN_SET('$array[$x]', title) != ",0); 
       } 
    $this->db->group_end();
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please accept the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and upvote if it is useful.